# Creating a record for a custom object and attaching a relevant pdf using dataloader

Tags: custom-object, data-loader

I have a custom object called 'Document Review', which contains a serious of questions that reviewers will need to answer when reviewing a single document. The documents themselves come in batches of 25-500. Is it possible using dataloader to:

a) create a new entry for the custom object for each document in the batch
b) attach the document to the custom object entry so that the reviewers do not need to leave the Salesforce ecosystem to complete the review

I am fairly familiar with the Salesforce platform but havnt gone anywhere near Apex / Apex development, so im hoping to avoid that if possible.

Any thanks is really appreciated!